# Java guessing game can't guess odd numbers in 10 guesses

Tags: java, loops

So for my java class, we have to guess what number the user is thinking of, between 0 and 1024. We have to guess the number within 10 guesses. I can't get odd numbers in 10 guesses, I can only get them in 11. This is what I have so far:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class guessing_game {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int high, low, middle;
     String input;
    int totalGuesses;
    high = 1024;
    low = 0;
    totalGuesses = 0;
    String name;

    System.out.println("What is your name?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = scan.nextLine();

        middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    System.out.println("Is your number higher than " + middle + ", " + name + "? Please answer 'y' or 'n'. ");
    System.out.println("If I guess the number, either answer 'that is my number' or answer 'n'.");
        totalGuesses++;
        Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = sca.nextLine();

        while (high - low != 1){
if (input.equals("y")){
            low = middle;
        middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    System.out.println("Okay, let's try again.");
    System.out.println("Is your number higher than " + middle + ", " + name + "? ");
        input = sca.nextLine();
        totalGuesses++;}
if (input.equals("that is my number")){
    System.out.println("Great! Your number is " + middle + ". ");
    break;}


else if (input.equals("n")){
            high = middle;
        middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    System.out.println("Alright, I'll try again.");
    System.out.println("Is your number higher than " + middle + ", " + name +  "? ");
        input = sca.nextLine();
        totalGuesses++;}
if  (high - low == 1){
    System.out.println("Number is " + high);
    break;}
if (high - low == 2){
    System.out.println("Your number is " + high);
    break;}}

    System.out.println("This guessing game program used " + totalGuesses + " guesses.");
    sca.close();
    scan.close();

     }
```

And this is the p-code my professor gave me on a word doc to help:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
Start of main method
    integer high,low,middle;
    String input;
    integer totalGuesses;
    high = 1024;
    low = 0;
    totalGuesses = 0;

    start infinite loop
        middle = low + (high - low)/2
        print "Is your number higher than " + middle + " ? (y/n)"
        increment totalGuesses by 1
        read from keyboard into input
        if input is “y”
            low = middle
            middle = low + (high - low)/2               
            if (high - low) == 1
                print "Your number is " + high
                exit the infinite loop

        else
            high = middle
            middle = low + (high - low)/2
            if (high - low) == 1
                print "Your number is " + low
                exit the infinite loop



    print "The program used " + totalGuesses + " guesses"

end of method
```

end of class

Comment: Probably debugger helps you better.

Comment: I would probably interpret "Infinite loop" as `while(True)`, by the way

Answer (score 1):

`middle = low + (high - low) / 2;` will not evaluate correctly if `high - low` is an odd number. The result will be *truncated* due to the division taking place in integer arithmetic.